What password hash type or method does blazor web app use by default
When you create a blazor project with individual accounts. What is the password hash type or method they use in the scaffolded code?
Tried looking for it but couldnt find a straight answer I thought it might orignally be SHA-256 but i am now not sure so if anyone knows it would be very helpful.

The asp.net core identity hash password using PasswordHasher which applys PBKDF2.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs. 
PBKDF2 is key derivation function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2
